# How to convert the result after running segment anything model SAM into a polygon shapefile

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, semantic-segmentation

I am using Meta AI Segment anything model to generate the polygon segmented. How can I convert the result into a polygon in the shapefile format?My script is below:

```
 import cv2
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from segment_anything import SamAutomaticMaskGenerator

mask_generator = SamAutomaticMaskGenerator(sam)

image_bgr = cv2.imread(r'C:\000000000000.tif')
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
masks = mask_generator.generate(image_rgb)
```